# I am using blender's rigify, I have parented my rig to my underlying mesh but unfortunately in pose mode nothing seems to be moving

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, rigify

I feel like I am missing something very simple. I used rigify and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAhbO7U1ID8 (which I think I followed pretty well) to try to rig a mesh of a human in 3D. While I can move the rig, the mesh and underlying bones do not transform at all. I feel like (and hope) this is an easy fix that I don't yet understand.

Blend file: [image]

Comment: Can you share your blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  You do have to be in _Pose_ mode to move the bones and have the mesh move as a result.  Are you?  Also, were there any errors when you parented the rig?  Often parenting with automatic weights fails.

Comment: I can definitely share the blender file. Is the best place to do that here or should I send it directly? I was trying to manipulate everything in pose mode. It didn't seem to have any errors (aside from that I deleted the face rig but forgot to delete the nose bone so I had to address that). When I go to automatic weights I see the only model is blue aside from a small region of the hand that is red.

Comment: share it using blend-exchange.  (See the link in the parenthesized remark in my first comment.)

Comment: Hi sorry, don't know how I missed that! Maybe that is reflective of something I missed in the model so apologies in advance

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=x6OjAJ58" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/x6OjAJ58/)

Comment: Additionally, while this model is not intended to be sexual in any manner, but it is supposed to represent an anatomical correct male body. While I don't think the mesh is particularly graphic it might warrant a very mild NSFW warning. It hasn't been shaded or coloured at all I just wanted to give a heads up.

Comment: I think this worked (partially?) to get it moving but now the model seems duplicated? When I move the leg it seems like there are two meshes that are moving independently, one that is deforming and one that is bending. Did I make a mistake in the execution of this fix, could something have happened under the vector deletion phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a common problem that I wish people writing tutorials would spend time discussing.  When you created your mesh you managed to create some duplicate vertices.  Unfortunately, the error message that tells you this is cryptic and flashes by very quickly.

Here's how to fix it:

- Select the mesh in *object mode*
- In the properties editor, under Object Properties, open the *Relations* panel and click on the 'x' next to "rig" to remove the parenting.

  [image]
- In the properties editor, under Object Data Properties, click the drop down on the right side of Vertex groups and select "Delete all groups"

  [image]
- In *edit mode* type <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and then type <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the merge menu and select "By Distance".

  [image]

  In the bottom status bar a message will briefly appear, saying how many vertices were removed.

  [image]
- In *Object*  mode, select the mesh and then the generated rig.
- type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> and select with automatic weights.

  [image]

  This is where the error message would have flashed across the bottom status bar before you cleared the duplicate vertices.  But it goes by quickly and the tutorials never mention it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix! I think this worked (partially?) to get it moving but now the model seems duplicated? When I move the leg it seems like there are two meshes that are moving independently, one that is deforming and one that is bending. Did I make a mistake in the execution of this fix, could something have happened under the vector deletion phase?